# PowerBI - How to count same values from multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

This is my first question here.
This time I want to count values that appear in different columns. Each one corresponds to the values from a row, but there is only 1 column that they have in common (not shown in the picture). I need a measure to show a count of each word described in those cells.
For example, in this case (please ignore blanks, it's a test), the measure should give a count for the word 'Desodorante' as 3, 'Cabello' as 2, and the rest 1. These words are pre defined and there are no random values accepted.
I may say that I want to state each of these words as a kind of category. I would like to make a slicer out of them too.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGSNC.png)

I believe a workaround is to create a calculated table, stating as columns each of these values and allocating a count of each value from these 4 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A Power Query solution to this problem has been posted here: [PowerBI - Count instances of string in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73761997/powerbi-count-instances-of-string-in-multiple-columns/73762300#73762300)
2. A DAX solution to this problem would be to create a new calculated table by appending the 4 columns using UNION() and SELECTEDCOLUMN() and then getting the count via SUMARIZE():

The 2 calculated Tables:

```
Mesa = 
FILTER(
    UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Ramiro',
            "Producto", 'Ramiro'[Producto]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Ramiro',
            "Producto", 'Ramiro'[Producto2]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Ramiro',
            "Producto", 'Ramiro'[Producto3]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Ramiro',
            "Producto", 'Ramiro'[Producto4]
        )
    ),
    [Producto] <> BLANK()
)
```

```
Producto Count = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Mesa',
    'Mesa'[Producto],
    "Count", COUNT('Mesa'[Producto])
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is i cannot unpivot those columns because they are a calculated table. I already appended all the values from the 4 columns into 1, but there is no fuction such as SUMARIZETABLE() for me. I would still need to count those strings.

Comment: But it looks like you have the exactly same homework as the questioner yesterday?

Comment: It seems like i do, yes. In case it is the same solution, I think I don't get it, sorry. I do have more values associated to those columns in the same rows and that's why i cannot unpivot them

Comment: Look at the measures I just added.